# Error while executing API method: calendar.addEvent

Tags: trigger.io

I am trying to add trigger.io native calender to my trigger.io application. But I am getting "Error while executing API method: calendar.addEvent".

I couldn't get any idea regarding this. Please suggest me how can I solve this error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: yes. error is "Error while executing API method: calendar.addEvent"

Answer (score 1):

Below code may be help you.

```
forge.calendar.addEvent({
    title: "Anniversary of adding my first event",
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    allday: true,
    recurring: "yearly"
}, function () {
    alert("Event added!");
});
```

For more you can take reference of [This link](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2013/03/21/new-feature-roundup-calendar-module-integrate-remote-web-content-into-your-app-and-more/)

Comment: Thank you. I hope I have used same code.  By clicking on the button getting error "Error while executing API method: calendar.addEvent". 

var mainButton = forge.tabbar.addButton({
 text: "calendar",
 icon: "calendar.png",
 
}, function (button) {
 button.onPressed.addListener(function () {
  forge.notification.alert("Any Title", "This is default alert box", function (){});
forge.calendar.addEvent({
    title: "Anniversary of adding my first event",
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    allday: true,
    recurring: "yearly"
}, function () {
    alert("Event added!");
});
 });
});